# is there any automated testing tool to test an android apk?

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, robotium, testautomationfx

I am told to make an automation testing using android apk only. I tried to use robotium but it requires me to use eclipse. I am currently using android studio. If there is any can you include a link to its tutorial? Thank you.

Comment: http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/robotium-tutorial-android-application-ui-testing-tool/

Comment: Thank you so much but is there any tutorial for android studio please ?

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing

Comment: Yes, there are many testing tools. `Espresso` is google's current recommendation, but there are some options such as Robotium and Appium

Comment: I suggest looking at [Google's Testing Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html).

Comment: @RafaelCardoso yes I have tried using espresso but it requires me source  code and I am told to use apk only. Also I am not allowed to decompile the apk. :(

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Appium](http://appium.io/). It is a test automation tool for native mobile app testing. It drives iOS and Android apps using the WebDriver protocol.

[Documentation Link](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#about-appium)